# Visual Studio and TestFlight - how to include symbols

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, testflight, visual-studio-mac

I am creating a Xamarin Forms app which I have uploaded to TestFlight

I am using Visual Studio which now includes the ability to post your archived build directly onto TestFlight

However when browsing the app on TestFlight, it says symbols were not included with the build

I can see by browsing through the project folder that a .dSYM was generated

How do I stipulate using Visual Studio (on Mac) should include this with the upload?

Comment: Hi , do you use a  *App Store distribution profile* for TestFlight ?

Comment: I think it is the development profile

Comment: You can have a look at this document about **Provisioning in TestFlight**:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos#provisioning

Comment: It's a shame most of the documentation focuses on Xcode when I'm trying to use visual studio

Comment: Okey , sometimes we will miss that when using TestFlight in Xamarin iOS preject .I think it's one part of difference with Xcode .

Comment: I have update this as an asnwer . If *App Store distribution profile* solve this finally , remember to mark that when you have time. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I've also added a comment, to the effect the visual studio upload feature is basically pointless as it stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aboud **[Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos#provisioning)** in TestFlight :

To test your builds with **TestFlight**, you will need to create an ***App Store distribution profile*** with the new beta entitlement. This entitlement allows beta testing through TestFlight, and any new App Store distribution profile automatically contains this entitlement. You can follow the step-by-step instructions in the [Creating a Distribution Profile guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning#provisioningprofile) to generate a new profile.

You can confirm that your distribution profile contains the beta entitlement when [validating your build in Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store), as illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: OK so basically as far as I can tell there is no point using Visual Studio's new upload feature since when you go to Xcode to validate the app it throws an error as that build number already exists